# Best practice multi-developers team Xcode4 project

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I wonder if there's a best practice when sharing Xcode4 project between multi-developer team. I keep getting problems with .xcodeproj files being corrupted and build problems after every git pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is this - when you get a conflict in project.pbxproj always take in changes from both sides.  Then everyone who added or removed files is happy. 99% of the time this works.

If you are getting corrupted project files after a pull, that means that someone is not doing a build before a push.  That's the root source of your problem, someone is not understanding what conflicts mean and that they need to be resolved.  You need to find that person and show them how to resolve conflicts in files.

Comment: That's how we are currently doing it. But I am wondering is there's a better way to do it. Thanks!